# How can I lose weight more effectively with bodybuilding?

Tags: weight-loss

I heard something about the simultaneous practice. To the best of my knowledge, it means that one can do some exercises after bodybuilding to lose more fats. Is it true? What is the best way? I'm 81 kg and I wanna be 75 kg.

Comment: Walking (extending into hiking) has one of the best fat burn ratios. Its low impact (almost zero risk on injuries) and everyone can do it. Quote:  "However, the distance you walk is equally important in losing belly fat. A regular, slow walk will burn about three quarters of a calorie per kilogram of body weight. This would be about 70 calories a mile if you weigh 200 pounds. A fast, brisk walk will burn about 125 calories a mile if you weigh 200 pounds."

Comment: Actually, I have a short running on the treadmill after exercise. It is about 10 min or 1400 meter (80 Cal). Is it a good way? May it bad for my bodybuilding exercises?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the beginning, you can gain muscle and lose fat at the same time, but only at the beginning (if you did not do a lot of sports before).

My stuff: When I started, I lost about 10 kg of weight and gained 4-5 kg of muscle in the same time (about 6-8 months). I'm not a exception, and I gained a lot more muscle after that.

So simply:

1. Do basic polyarticular exo (bench, squat, rowing, pull-up, etc.) and try to progress on each session. Progress is the key.
2. Cut transformed food from your alimentation : junks food, groceries, etc => to the trash. Eat more vegetable, eggs, fruits, meat, fish (Omega 3 is very underestimated).
3. Note your progression: what you eat, what you bench, weigh yourself one time a week.

If you can, read or watch videos to learn knowledge. YouTube has corrupted information, since everyone want to be a star, then invents a new exo/diet to shine.

Books have a lot more chance to be true, since it's harder to publish book than video, and writers have a LOT more experience generally.

Answer (score 0):

You don't lose weight in the gym.  You lose it in the kitchen.

Exercise will add muscle, and enough will burn some fat, and if you grow enough muscle you'll raise your basal metabolic rate a bit (muscle burns more calories than fat even just sitting there).  But to a first approximation, losing weight means eating less.

If you do eat less be sure to also eat better, you may be getting everything you need now, but may not be if you simply chop 10% off the top.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Weight gain ( preferably muscle gain) and fat loss are two exactly opposite things. You can not gain and lose at the same time. For gaining, you’ll have to go for a calorie surplus diet and fir fat loss, a calorie deficit diet is required. There are not some “magical” exercises. You can control amout of fat gain though by lifting heavy, compound movements and cardio in your routine with a specialised diet plan.

Answer (score -1):

Take a lighter weight and repeat exercise 50 to 100 times as a way to burn constant calories! I try to do 12 separate weight assisted exercises for 33 to 66 repeats and continue to move to the next one within a minute of each other to keep heart rate high and burn constant calories! It takes about a half hour and the soreness is minimal afterwards. Maybe ride an exercise bike prior to or afterwards for 10 minutes to burn calories longer. The pin machines, used in fitness centers, provide for an easy change of weight and can allow for increase or decrease in the lifted weight quickly if need be, to allow for more high reps or added weight levels to help a final increase of strength gains.

Comment: "The pin machines" as you call them are the worst way to lose fat in the gym. If you want to lose weight you can do two things, either do cardio style training, ie cycling, or you can do heavy compound lifts which incorporate a lot of muscles at the same time. Machines only target 1, maaaaybe 2 at best muscles at a time. This does NOT burn a lot of calories. If you want to lose fat without cardio, just do heavy deadlifts and squats, they burn a lot of calories.

Comment: I do 60 repeats at 12 exercises and stay busy for a half hour. I never do heavy weights one time. Get it right!  Was a PE teacher and national swim coach for 35 years. You answer is bull and I lost 10 pounds doing this type of repeat exercises!

Comment: I never said your way of losing weight doesn't work, I only said your way of losing weight is not the most optimal way to do this. What ever your personal experience is is anecdotal. You can simply measure in a scientific way that you will use more calories doing heavy (full body) compound exercises like a deadlift. Machines often only work 1 or 2 muscles at a time, which is the obvious reason why they don't require a lot of energy compared to a compound movement. You don't need to experience this for 35 years to understand this.